# код в scss не компилируется в style.css

Tags: css, scss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]использую редактор кода visual studio code, live sass compile не выдает никаких ошибок и успешно запускается (p.s основная часть кода скомпилирована с помощью онлайн компилятора кроме последнего свойства) оно и не применилось

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: brown;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: bisque;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  &:hover {
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

Comment: Непонятно в чём проблема, вы показываете нам успешно скомпилированный файл. Причём кружочек в заголовке намекает, что открытая в редакторе версия отличается от той, которая записана в файле в данный момент

Comment: мне уже пришлось использовать онлайн компилятор  кроме последнего свойства, обратите на него внимание, должно было автоматически скомпилироваться